# Seekport Crawler not blocking

Tags: .htaccess

Hello I am receiving visit from seekport crawler (just a few but I want to avoid them at all).

The rule now is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} OnalyticaBot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "=Re-re Studio (+http://vip0.ru/)" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "=Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Seekport Crawler; http://seekport.com/" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

All this one works, but there is another seekport crawler user agent with this string: "'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Seekport Crawler; [http://seekport.com/'"](http://seekport.com/%27%22) (the same but using ' and the begging and at the end).
Using `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "='Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Seekport Crawler; http://seekport.com/'"`  is not working, the ones with this "new" user agent are not blocked.

May I have to use any character like "" anywhere?. Maybe the problem is the char ' at the end and the beggining??

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Seekport [NC]
```

To block all Seekport crawlers…